# Google Auth runs in Visual studio but hangs when deployed to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I am working with the [Google .Net client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client).  The way it works is when a user wants to authenticate to Google the library spawns a new webpage for the user to authenticate with.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(authorizationUrl);
```

My code using the library

```
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
    scopes,
    userName,
    CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

If I run this locally via Visual studio it works fine.  However if I try to deploy it just hangs.   If run it using Visual studio using Local IIS.  I get the following error.

> System.Exception: CreateServiceAccountAnalyticsReportingFailed --->
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo
>   startInfo) at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo
>   startInfo) at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.d__6.MoveNext() in
>   C:\Apiary\v1.22\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\Support\GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4\OAuth2\LocalServerCodeReceiver.cs:line
>   89 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was
>   thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.d__8.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Apiary\v1.22\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\Support\GoogleApis.Auth\OAuth2\AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.cs:line
>   77 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was
>   thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__4.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Apiary\v1.22\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\Support\GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4\OAuth2\GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs:line
>   134 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was
>   thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__1.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Apiary\v1.22\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\Support\GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4\OAuth2\GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs:line
>   60 --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean
>   waitCompletionNotification) at
>   WebApplication1.WebForm1.AuthenticateOauth(String clientSecretJson,
>   String userName) in C:\Users\daimto\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\index.aspx.cs:line 69
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at WebApplication1.WebForm1.AuthenticateOauth(String clientSecretJson,
>   String userName) in C:\Users\daimto\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\index.aspx.cs:line 83 at
>   WebApplication1.WebForm1.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   C:\Users\daimto\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\index.aspx.cs:line 31
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data\MyGoogleStorage

I am not a system admin type person I have very little understanding of IIS.  My guess is that IIS doesn't have the permissions to be able to spawn the process?  This is just a guess.  I have tried setting the application pool to use my own personal account, I have tried network system  as well.

Links to the following issues on the Client library

- [Time](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/898)
- [GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync keeps on hanging when it is hosted on IIS](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/888)
- [Google Calendar Api-Time out exception on IIS](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/726)

Comment: It works fine *when the browser host and the server are the same machine*, which is what you experience during development. Random servers on the internet are not (meant to be) allowed to launch new programs on users machines. If you want to open a new *browser window*, you need to do that client-side with javascript.

Comment: This library has been live for years and we have never had a problem before.

Comment: Maybe so, but the *way that you're trying to use it* doesn't work and will not work.

Comment: https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/a5288c4493a12791b46f7142efacb83c4fcacf58/Src/Support/GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4/OAuth2/LocalServerCodeReceiver.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library supports another way of authenticating for use with Web Apps.

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;

namespace Google.Apis.Sample.MVC4
{
    public class AppFlowMetadata : FlowMetadata
    {
        private static readonly IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                {
                    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId = "PUT_CLIENT_ID_HERE",
                        ClientSecret = "PUT_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE"
                    },
                    Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                    DataStore = new FileDataStore("Drive.Api.Auth.Store")
                });

        public override string GetUserId(Controller controller)
        {
            // In this sample we use the session to store the user identifiers.
            // That's not the best practice, because you should have a logic to identify
            // a user. You might want to use "OpenID Connect".
            // You can read more about the protocol in the following link:
            // https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login.
            var user = controller.Session["user"];
            if (user == null)
            {
                user = Guid.NewGuid();
                controller.Session["user"] = user;
            }
            return user.ToString();

        }

        public override IAuthorizationCodeFlow Flow
        {
            get { return flow; }
        }
    }
}
```

Code stolen from [Web applications (ASP.NET MVC)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc)

Comment: Any help with this on aspnetcore

Comment: should be similar on asp. net core

Comment: No the demo that is demonstrated in google documentation is using mvc package which isn't available for core yet.

Comment: you can GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new with asp .net core the code should be similar your going to have to try or wait two weeks until I get back from vacation and can put up some of the code I use

Comment: Thanks @DaImTo I can wait for 2 weeks but until then I will try the javascript api route to achieve this. Waiting for your updates. Will put a reminder after 2 weeks here.